# Find string value in comma-separated list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list(string) with members in the form of 'label,location'; labels are distinct. I need a method which accepts a label parameter and returns a location.

I can iterate through using foreach to find the correct label, then manipulate the list member using Split to return the location. However I'm sure there's a better way, presumably using LINQ, along the lines of

```
return theList.Single(x => x == theLabel);
```

This doesn't work however since the list values == label,location.

Comment: `theList` is a list of strings?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary<string,string> ?

Comment: Yes the list is a list of strings, eg: label1,location1 then label2,location2. As far as using a dictionary, I'm not opposed to that but iterating over the list is already very straightforward. I was hoping there was a one- or two-line LINQ option.

Comment: @xnguyeng Iterating a dictionary is just as straightforward, and lookups would not require linq, Dictionary is certainly the way you should be doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below:

```
string get_location(List<string> list, label)
{
  return list.Select(s => s.Split(',')).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1])[label];
}
```

If there are multiple requests on the same list, then it is better to save that dictionary and then reuse for all labels queried:

```
var map = list.Select(s => s.Split(',')).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
```

Alternatively:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
list.ForEach(s => { var split = s.Split(','); map.Add(split[0], split[1]); });
```

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks. What is the function of [label] at the end? Aren't the key and value assigned in the first lambda expression?

Comment: [label] finds Value corresponding to Key == label in the Dictionary.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks. While others have suggested skipping the List altogether (since the source is csv) and going straight to dictionary, you were first with the correct answer to my incompletely-described question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the labels are unique, you might consider converting your data to a `dictionary<string,string>`. You can keep the label as the **key** and location as the **value**.

```
var lableLocatonDict = theList.Select(item => item.Split(','))
                                      .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0], arr => arr[1]);
```

Now to access a location(value) for a specific label(key) you can simply do this

```
var location = lableLocatonDict["LabelToCheck"];
```

You can use the ContainsKey method if you want to check whether an item exists in the dictionary before accessing it.

```
if(lableLocatonDict.ContainsKey("LabelToCheck"))
{
    var location = lableLocatonDict["LabelToCheck"];
}
```

Or the `TryGetValue`

```
var location = string.Empty;
if(lableLocatonDict.TryGetValue("LabelToCheck",out location))
{
   // location will have the value here             
}
```

Comment: Judging on his other questions, its managed data, so he should just store it as dict right off the bat and forgo the list and conversions.

Comment: I totally agree with that @Wobbles.

Comment: You are correct @Wobbles, the values are stored in a well-formed and structured csv file. I already had a method to read csv into a List, so I was proceeding from there. Perhaps I should ask a new/better question: how to read csv directly into a Dictionary :).

Comment: @xnguyeng see below, if it is a CSV, I recomend to forgo everything else weve said and use some sort of `Enumerable<T>` Additionally, if the CSV is data that is only from and used by your application, there are much better and easier serialization formats out there, I have become partial to JSON lately.

Answer (score 1):

As I and the other 2 answers recommend, Dictionary was designed for exactly this purpose. You expressed concern with iterating a dict as opposed to a list thinking it could be more difficult, but in fact it is easier since no splitting would be needed (and faster).

```
Dictionary<String,String> locations = new Dictionary<String,String>();

//How to add locations
locations.Add("Sample Label","Sample Location");

//How to modify a location
locations["Sample Label"] = "Edited Sample Locations";

//Iterate locations
foreach (var location in locations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(location.key);
    Console.WriteLine(location.value);
}
```

I would even go a bit further and say to future proof your application and add the ability for more information to be stored in each location, you should really be using `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T` is a custom class object:

```
public class LocationInfo
{
    String Label {get;set;}
    String Location {get;set;}
    String Description {get;set;}
}

ObservableCollection<LocationInfo> Locations = new ObservableCollection<LocationInfo>();
```

Comment: Thanks @Wobbles I will see if I can implement along the lines you are describing.